# Add custom header in FormData request

Tags: node.js, form-data

I have a Node function that uploads a file to an endpoint using FormData:

```
const uploadFile = (filepath) => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const formData = new FormData();

    // Add file
    formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream(filepath));

    formData.submit(`${API_URL}/v2/upload_file`, (error, res) => {
      if (error) {
        return reject(error);
      }

      if (res.statusCode !== 201) {
        return reject(res.statusMessage);
      }

      return resolve(res);
    });
  });
};
```

This works fine. The problem is that after an update on the endpoint, a custom header with a token is now required:

> 'x-session-token': 'abc123'

I can't find a way to add this token. formData.append() only adds key-values to the body. I was reading the node source code but can't find a method or a way to add options like headers.

I also tried using fetch() adding the headers, but is not parsing the multipart/form-data body data in a valid format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://github.com/form-data/form-data#alternative-submission-methods)...

> In case you need to also send custom HTTP headers with the POST request, you can use the `headers` key in first parameter of `form.submit()`

```js
const url = new URL(`${API_URL}/v2/upload_file`);

formData.submit({
  headers: { "x-session-token": "abc123" },
  host: url.hostname,
  path: url.pathname,
  port: url.port,
  protocol: url.protocol,
}, (error, res) => {
  // ...
});
```

---

IMO this is pretty clunky, particularly having to parse the URL into its components. It also doesn't support query parameters.

I would prefer to use `fetch()`

```js
const uploadFile = async (filepath) => {
  const formData = new FormData();

  // Add file
  formData.append("file", fs.createReadStream(filepath));

  const res = await fetch(`${API_URL}/v2/upload_file`, {
    method: "POST",
    body: formData,
    headers: {
      ...formData.getHeaders(),
      "x-session-token": "abc123",
    },
  });

  if (!res.ok) {
    throw new Error(res.statusText);
  }

  return res.json(); // or res.text()
};
```

Comment: Using fetch ends up in a bad request because the body is `[object FormData]`. I will try to find a solution to that when I have time, but yes, it's way cleaner.

Comment: That would only happen if you stringified `formData` which I have definitely not done in my answer